# SQL Insert values INTO specific column where ID equals to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to perform an INSERT data into a table with specific table.

The example as follows:

Table A
`col1(PK)`, `col2`, `col3`
these three col already have value on it, lets say:

```
col1 col2 col3
 q    w     e
 z    x     c
```

currently I am adding a new column 4 to it

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD col4 int;
```

Now I want to add value to Table A col4, how do I perform such action? for example I am adding *1 to row q* and *2 to row z*

---

### UPDATE

As I try below for updating one row at a time, the query will be as follows:

```
UPDATE Table A set col4 = '1' where col1 = 'q'
```

the above query shall update the table and result looks like follows:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 q    w     e    1
 z    x     c
```

Or you guys can refer the answer from GordonLinoff, link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62096911?noredirect=1).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I already update my tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `update`:

```
update a
    set col4 = (case when col1 = 'q' then 1 else 2 end)
    where col1 in ('q', 'z');
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff , can you provide me a statement for updating one column :D

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I try it out, is it looks like this?
`UPDATE TABLE A set col4 = '1' where col1 = 'q'`
When I am trying to update just one column :D